# Post HTTP Request using javascript for salesforce

Tags: javascript

I want to integrate salesforce to Recosence(External Sytem). Use case is Recosense push data and that will save in salesforce. I have create a post http service and tested in postman its generating access token and record in SFDC. 
But how to do same things in javascript.

Request for Access Token :

```
URL : https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Method: POST
Header : 
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body :
grant_type:password
client_id:ConsumerKey
client_secret:SecretKey
username:Username@demo.com
password:Password+SecurityToken
```

Response :

```
{
    "access_token": "00D5D0000008fEc!ARYAQO00kV_ijefERL8GaRWJnLPRxBkKDc39yPGpdiVzHdEP7Lb4dOTVBuUw7INSslGQjMdyYYDZjPREHfXwqZCEsi4YPFbp",
    "instance_url": "-------------------------------------",
    "id": "https://test.salesforce.com/id/00D5D0000008fEcUAI/0057F000000fpWFQAY",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "issued_at": "-----------------------",
    "signature": "-------------------------------"
}
```

---

Request for Any API to Hit Salesforce(PUSH to SF):

```
URL: https://cs72.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact
Method: POST
Header : 
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer access_token(Fetched from request 1)
Body :
{"FirstName":"Test",
"LastName":"Vish",
"Email":"test.test@testemail.com"}
```

Response:

```
{
    "id": "0035D000002zHrNQAU",
    "success": true,
    "errors": []
}
```

I have tested in Javascript but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started), in the AJAX documentation in MDN. Also, if you are not concerned with older browser support, you could also take a look at the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that uses promises.